# WPF DataGridCell Style to set tooltip, pass current cell to ObjectDataProvider MethodParameters?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `DataGrid` that I've used a `DataGridCell` `Style` to create a tooltip for a certain column. What I need to do is to pass a different column's value to the `ObjectDataProvider` `Method` that I use. I'm thinking there may be a better way, I've sure someone will suggest a `Converter` somehow.

```
<UserControl x:Class="TechInventory.ucInv"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TechInventory"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="350" d:DesignWidth="425" Loaded="ucInv_Loaded">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="PartByLocation" ObjectType="{x:Type local:PartHelper}" MethodName="PartByLocation" IsAsynchronous="True" >
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters >
            1234
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
    <Style x:Key="cellStyleCenter" TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="cellStyleRight" TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Right" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="cellStyleOnHand" TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ToolTip" >
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource PartByLocation}}" >
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Location" Binding="{Binding LocationName}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="On Hand" Binding="{Binding OnHand}" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="cellStyleHighlight" TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=LowQuant}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="PaleVioletRed"/>
                <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=LowQuant}" Value="False" >
                <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="dgInv" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="False" FontSize="15" CanUserResizeRows="False" Margin="10,10,10,10"
              AlternatingRowBackground="Cornsilk" SelectionUnit="Cell" MouseLeftButtonUp="dgInv_MouseLeftButtonUp" RowEditEnding="dgInv_RowEditEnding" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Part Number" Binding="{Binding PartNumber}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Part Description" Binding="{Binding PartDesc}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="On Hand" Binding="{Binding OnHand}" CellStyle="{StaticResource cellStyleOnHand}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="QMin" Binding="{Binding QMin}" CellStyle="{StaticResource cellStyleCenter}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="QMax" Binding="{Binding QMax}" CellStyle="{StaticResource cellStyleCenter}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="To Order" Binding="{Binding ToOrder}" CellStyle="{StaticResource cellStyleHighlight}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Part SKU" Binding="{Binding PartSKU}" CellStyle="{StaticResource cellStyleRight}" IsReadOnly="True" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

PartsHelper uses a TableAdapter to query for a PartNumber (other column I need to grab).

```
    public class PartHelper
{
    private LocationInventoryTableAdapter invLocationAdapter;
    private TechinventoryDataSet.LocationInventoryDataTable locPartInvDataTable;

    public TechinventoryDataSet.LocationInventoryDataTable PartByLocation(string PartNumber)
    {
        invLocationAdapter = new LocationInventoryTableAdapter();
        locPartInvDataTable = invLocationAdapter.GetDataByPartNumber(PartNumber);
        return locPartInvDataTable;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using an EventSetter in the style. I then applied the style to the column.

```
<Style x:Key="cellStyleOnHand" TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="ToolTip" >
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Location" Binding="{Binding LocationName}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="On Hand" Binding="{Binding OnHand}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <EventSetter Event="ToolTipOpening" Handler="Setter_ToolTipOpening" />
</Style>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="On Hand" Binding="{Binding OnHand}" CellStyle="{StaticResource cellStyleOnHand}" />
```

Code behind. Works out the part number of the row, then uses PartsHelper.PartByLocation to fill the tooltip grid.

```
private void Setter_ToolTipOpening(object sender, ToolTipEventArgs e)
{
    var dgc = (DataGridCell)sender;
    var row = (DataRowView)dgc.DataContext;
    string partcell = row["PartNumber"].ToString();
    PartHelper partProv = new PartHelper();
    (dgc.ToolTip as DataGrid).ItemsSource = partProv.PartByLocation(partcell, site);
}
```